# Selenium(Python) grab text inside quotations

Tags: python, selenium, webautomation

I would like to print what you see below is the numbers inside data-userassetid, for future reference
how can i print those numbers inside the quotations, anything helps

```
<div class = "item-card-container" data-userassetid = "50904623348">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following code fragment:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('item-card-container')
asset_id = elem.get_attribute('data-userassetid')
```